# Android RecyclerView, оповестить об изменениях данных

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть список диалогов пользователя, и в нем периодично обновляются данные. 
Сами данные получаются в `sevice`, в реальном времени. Как уведомить мой `RecyclerView.Adapter` что данные изменились? Какие есть способы?

Сейчас адаптер выглядит так:

```
public class DialogAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DialogAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList items;
private ArrayList<String> dialogPosition;

public DialogAdapter(ArrayList items) {
    this.items = items;
    dialogPosition = new ArrayList();
    Dialog dialog;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        dialog = (Dialog) items.get(i);
        dialogPosition.add(String.valueOf(dialog.ownerId));
    }
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(App.context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_item, parent, false)
    );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    /* Code */
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    View itemView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.itemView = itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        App.openChat((Dialog) items.get(getPosition());
    }
}

public void setMsg(String body, int chat) {
    int position = dialogPosition.indexOf(String.valueOf(chat));
    if (position != -1) {
        notifyItemMoved(position, 0);
        Dialog dialog = (Dialog) items.get(position);
        dialog.body = body;
        items.remove(dialog);
        dialogPosition.remove(String.valueOf(chat));
        items.add(0, dialog);
        dialogPosition.add(0, String.valueOf(chat));
        notifyItemChanged(0);
    }
```

Но я более чем уверен что такой метод оповещения адаптера не из самых лучших. Да и методы `notifyItemChanged` из `notifyItemMoved` не работают.

Answer (score 1):

Для связи `service` и `activity`, используйте `broadcast receiver`.

Для обновления данных, `notifyDataSetChanged`.